# Display data in textbox dynamically in Winform usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller

I have a UserControl in Winform, which has `textbox1`. I have a separate controller class where the code execution happens.

Here is the controller class code:

```
foreach(DataRow Dtrw in DataTabl1.Rows)
{
    Usercontrol1 Uc = new Usercontrol();
    Uc.Textbox1.text = Dtrw["Col1"].ToString().Trim();
}
```

But this is not working, as `textbox1` is not accessible. Is there any other way I can implement it?

Answer (score 2):

On the textBox1 control `Modifiers` you can set it to public

[image: modifiers]

So it becomes accessible elsewhere.

Comment: Alternatively, make a string property directly on the usercontrol to act as proxy for TextBox.Text, to avoid inadvertently exposing other parts of the Textbox that belong private. For example, you probably don't want someone using your UserControl to change the TextBox's Top or Left properties.